# React Infinite Scroll with GraphQL

Tags: reactjs, typescript, graphql, next.js, infinite-scroll

i'm trying to wire up my page to fill more items via graphql on scroll utilizing infinite scroll. right now i'm running into the issue of the page refreshing on every scroll and then erroring out when it reaches the hasMore max. if anyone has any ideas on how to get this working, it would be a HUGE help. i'm using nextjs, typescript, graphql, and reactjs infinite scroll

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import gql from 'graphql-tag';
import InfiniteScroll from 'react-infinite-scroller';
import { useQuery } from '@apollo/react-hooks';
import { useRouter } from 'next/router';
import { withApollo } from '../../lib/apollo';

import { ErrorIndicator, LoadingIndicator, SubHeading } from '../../components/Atoms/';
import { Card, SubNav } from '../../components/Molecules/';
import { ArticleList, SixCards } from '../../components/Organisms/';
import { BREAKPOINT } from '../../constants/';
import { countryData } from '../../data/countryData';

export const queryCreator = (categories, count): any => gql`
{
  articles(lang: "en", categories: ["${categories}"], count: ${count}){
    id
    slug
    title
    content
    featuredImage
    creator {
      name
      id
    }
    categories {
      name
      id
    }
  }
}
`;

export const News: React.FC = () => {
  const [articleListState, updateArticleList] = useState({
    count: 8,
    articleList: []
  });

  const { count, articleList } = articleListState;
  const router = useRouter();
  const { categories } = router.query;
  const categoriesToQuery = categories ? categories.toString() : '';
  const formattedQuery = queryCreator(categoriesToQuery, count);
  const { loading, error, data } = useQuery(formattedQuery);

  if (error) {
    return <ErrorIndicator />;
  }

  if (loading) {
    return <LoadingIndicator />;
  }
  const { articles } = data;

  // updateArticleList({ count: 8, articleList: articles });

  const hasMore = () => count <= 13;
  const loadMore = () => {
    if (hasMore) {
      const addOne = count + 1;
      updateArticleList({ count: addOne, articleList: articles });
    }
  };

  const items = [];

  articleList.map((article) =>
    items.push(
      article && (
        <div className="article" key={article.id}>
          <Card key={article.id} article={article} size="short" />
          <style jsx>{`
            .article {
              padding: 6px 0;
              margin: 0 auto;
            }
          `}</style>
        </div>
      )
    )
  );
  console.log(items, count);
  return (
    <main className="articles-container">
      <SubNav />
      <SixCards articles={articles} />
      <div className="article-list">
        <InfiniteScroll
          pageStart={0}
          loadMore={loadMore}
          hasMore={hasMore()}
          loader={
            <div key={0}>
              <SubHeading title="Loading . . ." Tag="h5" />
            </div>
          }
        >
          {items}
          {/* <ArticleList articles={articleList} /> */}
        </InfiniteScroll>
      </div>
      <style jsx>{`
        main.articles-container {
          min-height: 80vh;
          display: flex;
          flex-direction: column;
          width: 80%;
          margin: 0 auto;
        }

        .article-list {
          display: flex;
          flex-direction: column;
          justify-content: center;
          // width: 100%;
          max-width: 1020px;
          margin: 10px auto;
          align-self: center;
        }

        @media only screen and (max-width: ${BREAKPOINT}px) {
          main.articles-container {
            width: 90%;
          }
        }
      `}</style>
    </main>
  );
};

export default withApollo(News);
```

Comment: @IvanKaloyanov do not make edits that don't add anything to the question

Comment: A _minimal_ reproducable case would help a lot.

Comment: the gist of it is: how to query GraphQL correctly using InfiniteScroll. this instance needs an Array of 'articles' it gets from the query, and then uses the state to update the list based on the 'count'. this count is injected into the query again, and then the Array of articles is updated with more items to render

Comment: i'm wondering if it's refreshing ever time since i'm using NextJS and that's server side rendering

Comment: finding guidance here, testing, will post if it's successful: https://sysgears.com/articles/how-to-implement-infinite-scroll-with-graphql-and-react/

Comment: Have you [read about](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/data/pagination/) `fetchMore` in Apollo client?

Comment: @Herku this may be the answer to my entire problem. testing now, will update soon. thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

I'm using React, Typescript, GraphQL, apollo/client, and graphql-tag for my queries.

In this sample, we are creating the RepoList component. This component will fetch a list of repo using Github's GraphQl using a searchTerm.

```
import React from 'react';
import { useDebounce } from 'use-debounce';
import gql from 'graphql-tag';
import { useQuery } from '@apollo/client';
import InfiniteScroll from 'react-infinite-scroll-component';

import RepositoryItem, { SkeletonRepositoryCard } from './RepositoryItem';


export const SEARCH_FOR_REPOS = gql`
  query($search_term: String!, $cursor: String) {
    search(query: $search_term, type: REPOSITORY, first: 15, after: $cursor) {
      repositoryCount
      edges {
        node {
          ... on Repository {
            id
            name
            description
            owner {
              login
              avatarUrl
            }
            stargazers {
              totalCount
            }
          }
        }
        cursor
      }
      pageInfo {
        endCursor
        hasNextPage
      }
    }
  }
`;

export interface RepoDetails {
  node: {
    id: string;
    name: string;
    description: string | null;
    owner: {
      login: string;
      avatarUrl: string;
    };
    stargazers: {
      totalCount: number;
    };
  };
}

interface SearchRepoData {
  search: {
    repositoryCount: string;
    edges: RepoDetails[];
    pageInfo: {
      endCursor: string;
      hasNextPage: boolean;
    };
  };
}

interface SearchRepoVars {
  search_term: string;
}

const RepositoryList: React.FC<{ searchTerm: string }> = ({ searchTerm }) => {
  const classes = useStyles();
  const [expandedRepo, setExpandedRepo] = React.useState<number | null>(null);
  const [nextCursor, setNextCursor] = React.useState<string | null>(null);
  const [deboucedSearchKey] = useDebounce(searchTerm, 500);

  const { data, loading, error, fetchMore } = useQuery<
    SearchRepoData,
    SearchRepoVars
  >(SEARCH_FOR_REPOS, { variables: { search_term: deboucedSearchKey } });

  // Reset every time the data change
  // We make sure the repos shrink when we make a new search
  React.useEffect(() => {
    setExpandedRepo(null);
  }, [data]);

  const handleFetchMore = () => {
    console.log('next');
    if (data)
      fetchMore({
        variables: {
          cursor: data.search.pageInfo.endCursor,
          search_term: searchTerm,
        },
      });
  };

  if (loading && searchTerm.length > 1)
    return (
     < ... render loader ... >
    );

  if (error)
    return (
      < ... render error ... >
    );

  if (!loading && searchTerm.length && data && !data.search.repositoryCount)
    return (
      < ... Render No Repo ... >
    );

  if (data && data.search.repositoryCount)
    return (
      <InfiniteScroll
        dataLength={data.search.edges.length}
        next={handleFetchMore}
        hasMore={data.search.pageInfo.hasNextPage}
        loader={<h4>Loading...</h4>}
        endMessage={
          <p style={{ textAlign: 'center' }}>
            <b>Yay! You have seen it all</b>
          </p>
        }
      >
          {data &&
            data.search.edges.map((repo, i) => (
              < ... render repo card ... >
            ))}
      </InfiniteScroll>
    );

  return <div>Please search for repos</div>;
};

export default RepositoryList;
```